# Angular show/hide reactive form controls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to ask if there is any 'simpler' solution to hide/show controls with validation in component depending on selected value?

Right now we are creating too much of code like:

```
        this.form.get('inputField1').setValidators([Validators.required]);
        this.form.get('inputField1').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.form.get('inputField2').clearValidators();
        this.form.get('inputField2').setValue(null);
        this.form.get('inputField2').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Maybe there is another machanisim which is simpler and without manipulating manually at all.

I created a snippet to describe what is the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvnmde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Greetings!

Comment: I think a disbaled input, with required validator, will not be in error, and will not be in the "formGroup.value" object. So instead of updating validators, you could juste "enable/disable" your formControls ?

Comment: @Random, you are right! I made a try and it looks much better, thanks a lot :)